# Fetch result as single array in single query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, join

I need to join tables and fetch output as single array in single query, even though a user has multiple address

My query:

```sql
SELECT user.name, address.address, user.place 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN address 
WHERE user.user_id = address.user_id 
GROUP BY user.name, address.address, user.place
```

Suppose a user has multiple address am currently getting output as two rows.Is there any way to collect all output values in a single array using single query.

Please help.

Comment: Does SQL Server really accept that statement? Syntax error according to ANSI SQL.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and it's expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use FOR XML statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            u.name, 
            STUFF((SELECT ';' + a.[address]
            FROM address a
            WHERE u.[user_id] = a.[user_id]
            FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as [address],
            u.place
FROM [user] u
```

Output will be like:

```
name    address         place
Mike    adr1;adr2;adr3  someplace
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help,may i know why this 'a' here , FROM address a

Comment: It s alias to `address` table, it is common way to refer to tables without writing it's all name. You give alias once in query and then refer to table columns with the help of alias. F.e. in my answer I gave alias to `address` table `a` and `user` table - `u`. Then I write `a.user_id` instead of `address.user_id`.

Comment: Ok, thank you.Am not much experienced in writing queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group_concat` in your query.

```
SELECT user.name, group_concat(address.address) as 'address', user.place 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN address 
WHERE user.user_id = address.user_id
```

Comment: As I know `group_concat` is MySQL feature, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Try ***FOR XML PATH('')***, it will join you addresses in one row:

```
select
    [user].[name],
    (select [address] + ', '
    from [address]
    where
        [user_id] = [user].[user_id]
    for xml path('')),
    user.place
from [user]
```